# java.io.NotSerializableException: java.beans.EventHandler

Tags: java, binary, objectoutputstream, eventhandler, notserializableexception

I have this exception I do not understand why it would be thrown or how should I handle it.

```
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            oos.writeObject(frame);
            oos.writeObject(list);
            oos.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

I believe the exception is being thrown when `oos.writeObject(frame)` is read. Here I am attempting to save the JFrame object to binary. Previously I was able to write this same object to XML similarly with an `XMLEncoder`.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.beans.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.swing.*;


 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class SaveFrame implements Serializable{
public static JFileChooser chooser;
public JFrame frame;
public JTextArea textArea;
public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args){
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));      
    SaveFrame test = new SaveFrame();
    test.initialize();
}

public void initialize(){

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 300);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    JButton loadXML = new JButton("LoadXML");
    frame.getContentPane().add(loadXML);
    loadXML.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "loadXML"));

    JButton saveXML = new JButton("SaveXML");
    frame.getContentPane().add(saveXML);
    saveXML.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "saveXML"));

    JButton loadBinary = new JButton("LoadBinary");
    frame.getContentPane().add(loadBinary);
    loadBinary.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "loadBinary"));

    JButton saveBinary = new JButton("SaveBinary");
    frame.getContentPane().add(saveBinary);
    saveBinary.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "saveBinary"));

    JButton storeData = new JButton("StoreData");
    frame.getContentPane().add(storeData);
    storeData.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "storeData"));

    JButton printData = new JButton("PrintData");
    frame.getContentPane().add(printData);

    textArea = new JTextArea(30,30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
    printData.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "printData"));


    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void loadXML(){
    int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream(file));
            decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}

public void saveXML(){
    if (chooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream(file));
            encoder.writeObject(frame);
            encoder.writeObject(list);
            encoder.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
public void storeData(){
    list.add(textArea.getText());
}
public void printData(){
    for(String s : list){
        textArea.append(s + " ");
    }
}
public void loadBinary() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
public void saveBinary(){
    if (chooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            oos.writeObject(frame);
            oos.writeObject(list);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
             }
          }
      } 
 }
```

I don't quite get why it works when I'm saving to XML but not to a binary file format. Everything I've read from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) of ObjectOutputStream and it's examples would lead me to believe that this should work as [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) does. I would print out my stack for you but this being a gui, I don't know how to enable that in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) pointed by you,

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams.

and as per [Java Doc of java.bean.EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html), it does not implement `Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you can possibly have been reading that would lead you to expect that.

The very `ObjectOutputStream` Javadoc you linked to specifically states

> Only objects that support the `java.io.Serializable` interface can be written to streams.

It requires the object passed to it and all objects reachable from it via non-static non-transient references to implement `Serializable`.

The `XMLEncoder` doesn't have that constraint.

Comment: Well I'm new to reading documentation. Thank you for pointing this out. I kept reading it and was not understanding what I was reading, clearly.

Comment: I think I never caught this because I don't know what objects support `java.io.Serializable`. Is there a list of types of objects which are and aren't? That is something that would be very useful. Thankyou @EJP & @Wand Maker for all your help so far. EDIT: This seems to be the list http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/class-use/Serializable.html  ...it says JFrame is supported.